# Can anyone help me in designing this properly

Tags: android, android-layout

i am having the following layout file

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/no_image" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageView1"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvWord1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvWord2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
</LinearLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView4"
        android:src="@drawable/edit" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView2"
        android:src="@drawable/delete" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:src="@drawable/speak_my_words" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

this is my updated image.

[image]

can you suggest me more.

updated capture with the help of  Sherif elKhatib explanation

[image]

Comment: I would suggest to go with `RelativeLayout`. Align the speaker-icon to parent-right and align edit and delete button to the left of the speaker icon. Try how far you come with this and post your RelativeLayout here. I'll try to help you further if you get stuck again.

Comment: ok thanks i will try the way you suggested

Comment: updated my question have a look at it

Comment: See the answer below - someone has done all the work for you already :-) Still, you should try to get a grip of the RelativeLayout, if is really great once you get to know it a little bit.

Comment: thanks for the answer i tried it earlier but i didnt get it work well.
But when i did a copy paste of the below code it worked well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use a RelativeLayout. Put everything as you wish.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/no_image" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvWord"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/linearlayout"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvword2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tvWord"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/tvWord"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvWord"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearlayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/edit" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/delete" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/speak_my_words" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: This really worked for me but i have a small modification here.
i need to get the edit delete and voice images in the middle of the screen when the text is large.
for the imageView1 i used  android:layout_centerVertical="true" which worked but what should i do to make the three buttons be in the middle

Comment: Here you go, you should center vertical the last image (sound) and align top the upper image with it. Check the edits to understand more.

Comment: thanks for the edit again but it just made the sound image to the middle and not the three edit delete and sound buttons to the middle.
can you suggest me further please

Comment: image2 is has `android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView4"` so it should be just beside the sound button which in turn is centered vertically. If your imageView4 is GONE then you might have problems

Comment: updated the design in the question with the help of your code. Have a glance at it

Comment: @SharathG try removing these lines `android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"`

Comment: I removed the line for the edit and delete images. But the result was the same. Can you suggest me further

Comment: @SharathG As i can dig any further now, check the answer now. This should work

Comment: hey thanks for the sample.
I tried using  android:layout_alignRight="something" which didnt solve my problem. But using android:layout_toRightOf="something" solved it.
Can you say what is the difference between the both please?

Comment: If view A is aligned Right using `alignRight` with View B, there right edge (vertical) will be the same. If view A is to the Right of another View B, it is a bit self-explanatory, but view A will be to the right of view B; meaning the left edge of View A will be the same as the right edge of View B

Comment: thanks i think this was the problem i faced at the beginning.
Thanks for the explanation too